# How to pass variables from gulp to javascript or coffeescript assets

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gulp

I'm using Coffeescript for my frontend projects, I've been using Middleman until now and I want to switch to Gulp. With Middleman I was able to do something like this:

```
if foo is "<%= bar %>"
  # do something
```

where `bar` is a variable in `config.rb`. I would like to do the same thing using Gulp. Is there a way to pass variables and/or functions from the gulpfile to the script assets?

Comment: Are you referring to this [middleman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/middleman)? Could you add a little more detail about how you're using middleman and what role you expect gulp to play in this system?

Comment: Ah no, I was referring to the [Middleman ruby app](https://middlemanapp.com/) which I previously used instead of gulp/grunt for generating assets. This bit `"<%= bar %>"` is `erb` sintax, so basically I was able to expose some variables and some helpers from a `config.rb` to any template :P

Comment: I ended up using `lodash` templates, gonna post an answer to my question soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `gulp-template` which compiles [lodash templates](https://lodash.com/docs#template) which look pretty much the same as `erb`. So let's take an example of a `slim` template, it usually looks like this:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title = project_title
  body
    #content
      - if html5?
        p Routes look like "example.com/some/route"
      - else
        p Routes look like "example.com/#!/some/route"

    #footer
      | Copyright © #{year} #{author}
```

which now translates to:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title <%= projectTitle %>
  body
    #content
      <% if isHtml5() { %>
      p Routes look like "example.com/some/route"
      <% } else { %>
      p Routes look like "example.com/#!/some/route"
      <% } %>

    #footer
      | Copyright © <%= year %> <%= author %>
```

Notice the code between `<% .. %>` is not ruby anymore, is plain javascript. You can use it in whatever crazy combination you want, but you have to think carefully about the output there: there is no indentation difference between `if .. else` and the paragraphs, as you would expect from a slim template.

To expose data to the template, pass an object to `gulp-template` like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var template = require('gulp-template');
var slim = require('gulp-slim');

gulp.task('slim', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/*.slim')
    .pipe(template({
      projectTitle: 'Example',
      year: '2015',
      author: "Master Yoda"
      isHtml5: function(){
        // ...
      }
    }))
    .pipe(slim({pretty: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Documentation can be found here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-template

For this particular case, an alternative would be `gulp-jade` for jade templates (similar to slim, but you can use vanilla jade syntax without the use of `gulp-templates`).

Other generic template engines include: swig, mustache, etc...